# Why UbuntuOne for iOS doesn't make  use of all the iPad screen?

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone, ipad

It is nice to see the Ubuntu One Files app for iOS, but why hasn't the additional work been done so that it also works well on larger screens of the ipad?

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Let me edit it a bit first.

Answer (score 4):

When building software you often have to make a call as to whether to release today with some features missing, or to release later with those features. It working well on ipad was deemed a “nice to have” feature, not critical enough to block release, and so was left for a later date.

We are aware of the deficiency however, and will be enhancing the app in this way as soon as we are able to do so without compromising other features or products on our roadmap.

Thank you for caring.